# Triangulate example for iBeacons

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am looking into the possibility to use multiple iBeacons to do a 'rough' indoor position location. The application is a kind of 'museum' setting, and it would be easier to be able to form a grid with locations for the different objects then individual beacons (although that might not be impossible too).

Are there examples, experiences, with using multiple beacons to triangulate into some kind of location, or some logic to help me on the way to write it myself?

Comment: Check out my demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMWEl6GBGqk . In the comments you will find a response from Jakub Krzych whose company produced the beacons that I'm using.

Comment: Thanks that is very useful. If Estimote is going to release an API then I might wait and see how that works instead of studying the maths myself and try to find a way to dynamically calibrate and correct the beacons as suggested in the comments.

Comment: @LuukD.Jansen I'm looking on this too... any news?

Comment: I haven't been able to look into it any further. I think triangulating will not be able to be accurate enough on the scale (floor space) I need it. It will be easier/cheaper to have a beacon on all important places

Answer (score 76):

I have been making some experiments to get a precise position using three beacons.

**Results of trilateration**

Unluckily, the results were very disappointing in terms of quality. There were mainly two issues:

1. In non-controlled environments, where you can find metals, and other objects that affect the signal, the received signal strength of the beacons changes so often that it seems impossible to get error range below 5 meters.
2. Depending on the way that the user is handling the receiver device, the readings can change a lot as well. If the user puts his/her hand over the bluetooth antenna, then the algorithm will have low signals as input, and thus the beacons will supposed to be very far from the device. See [this image](http://sotovik.ru//images/review/Apple/iPad3/an.jpeg) to see the precise location of the Bluetooth antenna.

**Possible solutions**

After talking with an Apple engineer who actively discouraged me to go down this way, the option I feel more inclined to use right now is brute force. Try to set up a beacon every X meters (X being the maximum error tolerated in the system) so we can track on this beacons grid the position of a given device by calculating which beacon on the grid is the closest to the device and assuming that the device is on the same position.

**Trilateration algorithm**

However, for the sake of completeness, I share below the core function of the trilateration algorithm. It's based on the paragraph 3 ("Three distances known") of [this article](http://everything2.com/title/Triangulate).

```
- (CGPoint)getCoordinateWithBeaconA:(CGPoint)a beaconB:(CGPoint)b beaconC:(CGPoint)c distanceA:(CGFloat)dA distanceB:(CGFloat)dB distanceC:(CGFloat)dC {
    CGFloat W, Z, x, y, y2;
    W = dA*dA - dB*dB - a.x*a.x - a.y*a.y + b.x*b.x + b.y*b.y;
    Z = dB*dB - dC*dC - b.x*b.x - b.y*b.y + c.x*c.x + c.y*c.y;

    x = (W*(c.y-b.y) - Z*(b.y-a.y)) / (2 * ((b.x-a.x)*(c.y-b.y) - (c.x-b.x)*(b.y-a.y)));
    y = (W - 2*x*(b.x-a.x)) / (2*(b.y-a.y));
    //y2 is a second measure of y to mitigate errors
    y2 = (Z - 2*x*(c.x-b.x)) / (2*(c.y-b.y));

    y = (y + y2) / 2;
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

Comment: I seem to always be getting either NaN or Inf+ for my y value. Did you ever encounter this while developing your algorithm?

Comment: No, I didn't have this problem. Make sure all input parameters are scaled into your UIView coordinate system. For example, if you are tracking a 10x10 meters space and drawing it into a 500x500 pixels UIView, then you need to multiply the beacons real positions and distances measured by 50.

Comment: I find that the formula for y sometimes breaks, particularly when points a and b have the same y coordinate. It's the `/ (2*(b.y-a.y))` part which produces a 0, then a division by zero error.

Comment: The coordinates for a, b and c represent a somehow static input to the algorithm, as they represent the fixed positions where you are locating the beacons that you are using to triangulate. Positioning two of these beacons in the same position won't give you any added valuable information about your current location.

Comment: This really helped me alot. I converted this method into Java and it worked out perfectly. Working with it as we speak.

Comment: Are the static coordinates of the beacons just their position in meters from a known origin (e.g. one of the beacons is 0,0 and the others are expressed relative to this)?

Comment: jdmunro It depends on how much surface you are drawing on your app. You need to convert the beacons coordinates from the real world into the digital world. Let's say you are covering (i.e. drawing) a 20mx10m surface and your map view on your app measures 400x200 pixels (so the conversion scale is 1m:20px). If you had one beacon positioned at x=3m and y=5m in the real world, then the CGPoint for that beacon would be x=60 and y=100 in your map view.

Comment: I agree this equation doesn't work. Beacons are set at 1.5mx2.5m and my uiview is 300x500. According to your multiplier my x.y comes out to be in the 4k pixels region

Comment: What if I only have 3 devices, how do i use this?

Comment: How to calculate or find CGPoint a, b and c in above method?

Comment: @JavierChávarri , for a wide area, i think we should use more than 3 beacons. Then, how can i locate the beacons, maybe honeycomb corners and centers? Which three should be used to decide the position of a device? Maybe the three with shortest distance, strongest signal strength at current position?

Comment: @merveotesi I had never used more than 3 beacons, but my first trial would be around what you propose, i.e. using the 3 closest beacons based on signal strength. Another option could be to pick up all different 3-sets available, calculate the center for each one of them, and then get the average center point from all of them. How are you planning to layout the beacons? Maybe like this? http://www7b.biglobe.ne.jp/~archer/primespiral/tri.png

Comment: @JavierChávarri , yes i exactly mean something like this

Comment: We have converted this code to C#  and it works fine. We doubled checked on paper and with the original formula in the link

Comment: GPS triangulation happens in same way but the more number of satellites we receive the signals from better the accuracy. Do we have any algorithms which would account for more number of beacons for a greater accuracy? Just curious!

Comment: what if having beaconA(50, 100) beaconB(100,100) beaconC(150, 100) with distanceA(111.803399) distanceB(100) and distanceC(111.803399), but it returns NaN, as it should return as (100,200)

Answer (score 24):

Here is an open source java library that will perform the trilateration/multilateration:
https://github.com/lemmingapex/Trilateration

[image: example]

It uses a popular nonlinear least squares optimizer, the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, from Apache Commons Math.

```
double[][] positions = new double[][] { { 5.0, -6.0 }, { 13.0, -15.0 }, { 21.0, -3.0 }, { 12.42, -21.2 } };
double[] distances = new double[] { 8.06, 13.97, 23.32, 15.31 };

NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver solver = new NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver(new TrilaterationFunction(positions, distances), new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());
Optimum optimum = solver.solve();

// the answer
double[] calculatedPosition = optimum.getPoint().toArray();

// error and geometry information
RealVector standardDeviation = optimum.getSigma(0);
RealMatrix covarianceMatrix = optimum.getCovariances(0);
```

Most scholarly examples, like the one on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration), deal with exactly three circles and assume perfectly accurate information.  These circumstances allow for much simpler problem formulations with exact answers, and are usually not satisfactory for practical situations.

The problem in R<sup>2</sup> or R<sup>3</sup> euclidean space with distances that contain measurement error, an area (ellipse) or volume (ellipsoid) of interest is usually obtained instead of a point.  If a point estimate is desired instead of a region, the area centroid or volume centroid should be used.   R<sup>2</sup> space requires at least 3 non-degenerate points and distances to obtain a unique region; and similarly R<sup>3</sup> space requires at least 4 non-degenerate points and distances to obtain a unique region.

Answer (score 16):

I looked into this. The term you want it trilateration. (In triangulation you have angles from 3 known points. In trilateration you have distance from 3 known points) If you Google it you should find several articles including one on Wiki. It involves solving a set of 3 simultaneous equations. The documents I saw were for 3D trilateration - 2D is easier because you can just drop the Z term.

What I found was abstract math. I haven't taken the time yet to map the general algorithm into specific code, but I plan on tackling it at some point.

Note that the results you get will be VERY crude, especially in anything but an empty room. The signals are weak enough that a person, a statue, or anything that blocks line of sight will increase your distance readings pretty significantly. You might even have places in a building where constructive interference (mostly from the walls) makes some places read as much closer than they actually are.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I will have a look at that. I know the shortcomings, but would like to do a test with it anyway. Accuracy within a few meters would be enough if it will save having to put a beacon on each point. Even if that is the way to go, I would like to test it out.

Answer (score 8):

Accurate indoor positioning with iBeacon will be challenging for the following reasons:

1. As pointed in earlier comments, iBeacon signal tend to fluctuate a lot. The reason include [multipath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation) effect, the dynamic object obstructions between the phone and iBeacon when the person is moving, other 2.4GHz interferences, and more. So ideally you don't want to trust 1 single packet's data and instead do some averaging for several packets from the same beacon. That would require the phone/beacon distance doesn't change too much between those several packets. For general BLE packets (like beacons from StickNFind) can easily be set to 10Hz beaconing rate. However for iBeacon, that'll be hard, because
2. iBeacon's beaconing frequency probably cannot be higher than 1Hz. I will be glad if anyone can point to source that says otherwise, but all information I've seen so far confirms this assertion. That actually make sense since most iBeacons will be battery powered and high frequency significantly impact the battery life. Considering people's average walking speed is [5.3km](http://www.reference.com/motif/health/average-walking-speed-of-adult-human) (~1.5m/s), so even if you just use a modest 3 beacon packets to do the averaging, you will be hard to get ~5m accuracy.

On the other hand, if you *could* increase iBeacon frequency to larger than 10Hz (which I doubt is possible), then it's possible to have 5m or higher accuracy using suitable processing method. Firstly trivial solutions based on the [Inverse-Square Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), like trilateration, is often not performing well because in practice the distance/RSSI relationship for different beacons are often way off from the Inverse-Sqare Law for the reason 1 above. But as long as the RSSI is relatively stable for a certain beacon in any certain location (which usually is the case), you can use an approach called *fingerprinting* to achieve higher accuracy. A common method used for fingerprinting is kNN ([k-Nearest Neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm)).

#### Update 2014-04-24

Some iBeacons *can* broadcast more than 1Hz, like Estimote use 5Hz as default. However, according to this [link](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/issues/18): "*This is Apple restriction. IOS returns beacons update every second, no matter how frequently device is advertising.*". There is another comment there (likely from the Estimote vendor) saying "*Our beacons can broadcast much faster and it **may** improve results and measurement*". So whether higher iBeacon frequency is beneficial is not clear.

Comment: Without looking much into it, I have a set of Estimote beacons, and the interval is by default set to 200 ms. However, it can be set to 50 ms (but naturally this will affect battery life)

Comment: In that case, can you see >1Hz ranging updates in you iOS app?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have proper code to test at the moment and to be honest haven't had the time to write it. I just saw the option some time ago and added the comment, but the update on the answer seems to suggest it doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

For those who need `@Javier Chávarri` trilateration function for `Android` devices (for saving some time):

```
public static Location getLocationWithTrilateration(Location beaconA, Location beaconB, Location beaconC, double distanceA, double distanceB, double distanceC){

    double bAlat = beaconA.getLatitude();
    double bAlong = beaconA.getLongitude();
    double bBlat = beaconB.getLatitude();
    double bBlong = beaconB.getLongitude();
    double bClat = beaconC.getLatitude();
    double bClong = beaconC.getLongitude();

    double W, Z, foundBeaconLat, foundBeaconLong, foundBeaconLongFilter;
    W = distanceA * distanceA - distanceB * distanceB - bAlat * bAlat - bAlong * bAlong + bBlat * bBlat + bBlong * bBlong;
    Z = distanceB * distanceB - distanceC * distanceC - bBlat * bBlat - bBlong * bBlong + bClat * bClat + bClong * bClong;

    foundBeaconLat = (W * (bClong - bBlong) - Z * (bBlong - bAlong)) / (2 * ((bBlat - bAlat) * (bClong - bBlong) - (bClat - bBlat) * (bBlong - bAlong)));
    foundBeaconLong = (W - 2 * foundBeaconLat * (bBlat - bAlat)) / (2 * (bBlong - bAlong));
    //`foundBeaconLongFilter` is a second measure of `foundBeaconLong` to mitigate errors
    foundBeaconLongFilter = (Z - 2 * foundBeaconLat * (bClat - bBlat)) / (2 * (bClong - bBlong));

    foundBeaconLong = (foundBeaconLong + foundBeaconLongFilter) / 2;

    Location foundLocation = new Location("Location");
        foundLocation.setLatitude(foundBeaconLat);
        foundLocation.setLongitude(foundBeaconLong);

    return foundLocation;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm trying your code, but don't understand the result it gave me ?
My 3 points are : 49.348657, 6.173041, 3.126m - 49.348658, 6.172981, 5.452m - 49.348588, 6.173028, 4.065m
Result I have in my Location : Latitude is alway -90,0 and Longitude change depending the distance ?
Any Idea ?

Comment: Check if your three location points create a triangle and they do not form a line. Im answering from phone. Once im in PC ill test your locations

Comment: @LordStJohn have you tried with another points? I mean do you always get that result?

Comment: Yes I tries with other points, always in same building. Always getting the same kind of results, Latitude is always -90.0 and longitude change with distance.

Comment: @LordStJohn i just tried with these stats: 49.348657, 6.173041, 3.126m - 49.348658, 6.172981, 5.452m - 49.348588, 6.173028, 4.065 and it doesnt give -90. Try `Debugging` and make sure you are using those locations.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, I will debug to find where do I something wrong.

Comment: Can someone suggest similar algorithm with altitude included?

Comment: @hrskrs, How did you find the distance from RSSI value of a beacon? Can you please tell me that?

Answer (score 6):

If you're anything like me and don't like maths you might want to do a quick search for "indoor positioning sdk". There's lots of companies offering indoor positioning as a service.

Shameless plug: I work for [indoo.rs](http://indoo.rs) and can recommend this service. It also includes routing and such on top of "just" indoor positioning.

Answer (score 5):

My Architect/Manager, who wrote the following algorithm,

```
public static Location getLocationWithCenterOfGravity(Location beaconA, Location beaconB, Location beaconC, double distanceA, double distanceB, double distanceC) {

    //Every meter there are approx 4.5 points
    double METERS_IN_COORDINATE_UNITS_RATIO = 4.5;

    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/524770/663941
    //Find Center of Gravity
    double cogX = (beaconA.getLatitude() + beaconB.getLatitude() + beaconC.getLatitude()) / 3;
    double cogY = (beaconA.getLongitude() + beaconB.getLongitude() + beaconC.getLongitude()) / 3;
    Location cog = new Location("Cog");
    cog.setLatitude(cogX);
    cog.setLongitude(cogY);


    //Nearest Beacon
    Location nearestBeacon;
    double shortestDistanceInMeters;
    if (distanceA < distanceB && distanceA < distanceC) {
        nearestBeacon = beaconA;
        shortestDistanceInMeters = distanceA;
    } else if (distanceB < distanceC) {
        nearestBeacon = beaconB;
        shortestDistanceInMeters = distanceB;
    } else {
        nearestBeacon = beaconC;
        shortestDistanceInMeters = distanceC;
    }

    //http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/conic-sections/distance-between-two-points-and-the-midpoint
    //Distance between nearest beacon and COG
    double distanceToCog = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cog.getLatitude() - nearestBeacon.getLatitude(),2)
            + Math.pow(cog.getLongitude() - nearestBeacon.getLongitude(),2));

    //Convert shortest distance in meters into coordinates units.
    double shortestDistanceInCoordinationUnits = shortestDistanceInMeters * METERS_IN_COORDINATE_UNITS_RATIO;

    //http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46527/coordinates-of-point-on-a-line-defined-by-two-other-points-with-a-known-distance?rq=1
    //On the line between Nearest Beacon and COG find shortestDistance point apart from Nearest Beacon

    double t = shortestDistanceInCoordinationUnits/distanceToCog;

    Location pointsDiff = new Location("PointsDiff");
    pointsDiff.setLatitude(cog.getLatitude() - nearestBeacon.getLatitude());
    pointsDiff.setLongitude(cog.getLongitude() - nearestBeacon.getLongitude());

    Location tTimesDiff = new Location("tTimesDiff");
    tTimesDiff.setLatitude( pointsDiff.getLatitude() * t );
    tTimesDiff.setLongitude(pointsDiff.getLongitude() * t);

    //Add t times diff with nearestBeacon to find coordinates at a distance from nearest beacon in line to COG.

    Location userLocation = new Location("UserLocation");
    userLocation.setLatitude(nearestBeacon.getLatitude() + tTimesDiff.getLatitude());
    userLocation.setLongitude(nearestBeacon.getLongitude() + tTimesDiff.getLongitude());

    return userLocation;
}
```

1. Calculate the centre of gravity for a triangle (3 beacons)
2. calculate the shortest distance / nearest beacon
3. Calculate the distance between the beacon and the centre of gravity
4. Convert the shortest distance to co-ordinate units which is just a constant, he used to predict accuracy. You can test with varing the constant
5. calculate the distance delta
6. add the delta with the nearest beacon x,y.

After testing it, I found it accurate to 5 meters.

Please comment me your testing, if we can refine it.

Comment: How did you convert the RSSI value as distance? How did you get the reference beacon's distance?

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented a very simple **Fingerprint** algorithm for android 4.4, tested in a relative 'bad' environment:

- nearly 10 wifi AP nearby.
- several other Bluetooth signals nearby.

the accurate seems in 5-8 meters and depends on how I placed that 3 Ibeacon broadcaster.
The algorithm is quite simple and I think you can implemented one by yourself, the steps are:

1. load the indoor map.
2. sampling with the map for all the pending positioning point.
3. record all the sampling data, the data should include:
   map coordinate, position signals and their RSSI.

so when you start positioning, it's just a reverse of proceeding steps.

Comment: Your fingerprinting algorithm uses trilateration or another technique?

Answer (score 3):

We are also trying to find the best way to precisely locate someone into a room using iBeacons. The thing is that the beacon signal power is not constant, and it is affected by other 2.4 Ghz signals, metal objects etc, so to achieve maximum precision it is necessary to calibrate each beacon individually, and once it has been set in the desired position. (and make some field test to see signal fluctuations when other Bluetooth devices are present). 
We have also some iBeacons from Estimote (the same of the Konrad Dzwinel's video), and they have already developed some tech demo of what can be done with the iBeacons. Within their App it is possible to see a Radar in which iBeacons are shown. Sometimes is pretty accurate, but sometimes it is not, (and seems phone movement is not being considered to calculate positions). Check the Demo in the video we made here: http://goo.gl/98hiza

Although in theory 3 iBeacons should be enough to achieve a good precision, maybe in real world situations more beacons are needed to ensure the precision you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that really helped me was this project on Code.Google.com: https://code.google.com/p/wsnlocalizationscala/  it contains lots of code, several trilateration algorithms, all written in C#. It's a big library, but not really meant to be used "out-of-the-box".

Answer (score 2):

Please check the reference https://proximi.io/accurate-indoor-positioning-bluetooth-beacons/

Proximi SDK will take care of the triangulation. This SDK provides libraries for handling all the logic for beacon positioning, triangulation and filtering automatically in the background. In addition to beacons, you can combine IndoorAtlas, Wi-Fi, GPS and cellular positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I found Vishnu Prahbu's solution very useful. I ported it to c#, if anybody need it.

```
public static PointF GetLocationWithCenterOfGravity(PointF a, PointF b, PointF c, float dA, float dB, float dC)
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332856/triangulate-example-for-ibeacons
        var METERS_IN_COORDINATE_UNITS_RATIO = 1.0f;

        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/524770/663941
        //Find Center of Gravity
        var cogX = (a.X + b.X + c.X) / 3;
        var cogY = (a.Y + b.Y + c.Y) / 3;
        var cog = new PointF(cogX,cogY);

        //Nearest Beacon
        PointF nearestBeacon;
        float shortestDistanceInMeters;
        if (dA < dB && dA < dC)
        {
            nearestBeacon = a;
            shortestDistanceInMeters = dA;
        }
        else if (dB < dC)
        {
            nearestBeacon = b;
            shortestDistanceInMeters = dB;
        }
        else
        {
            nearestBeacon = c;
            shortestDistanceInMeters = dC;
        }

        //http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/conic-sections/distance-between-two-points-and-the-midpoint
        //Distance between nearest beacon and COG
        var distanceToCog =  (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(cog.X - nearestBeacon.X, 2)
                + Math.Pow(cog.Y - nearestBeacon.Y, 2)));

        //Convert shortest distance in meters into coordinates units.
        var shortestDistanceInCoordinationUnits = shortestDistanceInMeters * METERS_IN_COORDINATE_UNITS_RATIO;

        //http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46527/coordinates-of-point-on-a-line-defined-by-two-other-points-with-a-known-distance?rq=1
        //On the line between Nearest Beacon and COG find shortestDistance point apart from Nearest Beacon
        var t = shortestDistanceInCoordinationUnits / distanceToCog;
        var pointsDiff = new PointF(cog.X - nearestBeacon.X, cog.Y - nearestBeacon.Y);
        var tTimesDiff = new PointF(pointsDiff.X * t, pointsDiff.Y * t);

        //Add t times diff with nearestBeacon to find coordinates at a distance from nearest beacon in line to COG.
        var userLocation = new PointF(nearestBeacon.X + tTimesDiff.X, nearestBeacon.Y + tTimesDiff.Y);

        return userLocation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Equation

```
- (CGPoint)getCoordinateWithBeaconA:(CGPoint)a beaconB:(CGPoint)b beaconC:(CGPoint)c distanceA:(CGFloat)dA distanceB:(CGFloat)dB distanceC:(CGFloat)dC {


CGFloat x, y;
x = ( ( (pow(dA,2)-pow(dB,2)) + (pow(c.x,2)-pow(a.x,2)) + (pow(b.y,2)-pow(a.y,2)) ) * (2*c.y-2*b.y) - ( (pow(dB,2)-pow(dC,2)) + (pow(c.x,2)-pow(c.x,2)) + (pow(c.y,2)-pow(b.y,2)) ) *(2*b.y-2*a.y) ) / ( (2*b.x-2*c.x)*(2*b.y-2*a.y)-(2*a.x-2*b.x)*(2*c.y-2*b.y) );

y = ( (pow(dA,2)-pow(dB,2)) + (pow(c.x,2)-pow(a.x,2)) + (pow(b.y,2)-pow(a.y,2)) + x*(2*a.x-2*b.x)) / (2*b.y-2*a.y);



return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```