# Android: Find my iBeacon Position

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am working on iBeacon Application, which will detect my nearest iBeacon and connect to it & serve further process.

I am done with finding my nearest iBeacon and get its all properties like: UUID, Accuracy, Major, Minor, RSSI, Transmiter Power etc.

Now i want to search that, iBeacon is in which direction from my device wheather it is left/right/top/bottom or any other direction corners?

Below my nearest iBeacon search list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible:

> Don't expect to be able to determine the direction to a beacon. Because beacons are typically omnidirectional transmitters, although you can estimate distance, you cannot estimate direction.

See: [Fundamentals of Beacon Ranging](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're trying to do is not possible using only one iBeacon. You are looking for something like trilateration which requires a minimum of 3 beacons. This might get you started [Triangulate example for iBeacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332856/triangulate-example-for-ibeacons)

Answer (score 1):

This technology works due to the fact that we know the coordinates originally iBeacon. To get the coordinates iBeacon you need to know at least their local coordinates. The application uses a local coordinate system on which iBeacons serve as reference points. If you do not know your coordinates and iBeacon then you will have nothing to calculate